# Using lapply with gsub to replace word in dataframe using another dataframe as 'dictionnary'

Tags: r, dictionary, lapply

I have a dataframe called data where I want to replace some word in specific columns A & B.
I have a second dataframe called dict that is playing the role of dictionnary/hash containing the words and the values to use for replacement.

I think it could be done with  purrr’s map() but I want to use apply.   It's for a package and I don't want to have to load another package.
The following code is not working but it's give you the idea. I'm stuck.

```
columns <- c("A", "B" ) 
data[columns] <- lapply(data[columns], function(x){x}) %>% lapply(dict, function(y){
         gsub(pattern = y[,2], replacement = y[,1], x)})
```

This is working for one word to change...but I'm not able to pass the list of changes conainted in the dictionnary.

```
data[columns] <- lapply(data[columns], gsub, pattern = "FLT1", replacement = "flt1")
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: What about base R's `Map` or `mapply`?

Comment: Or even a `for` loop...

Comment: or a named vector finally...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gregor_Thomas is right, you need a `for` loop to have a recursive effect, otherwise you just replace one value at the time.

```
df <- data.frame("A"=c("PB1","PB2","OK0","OK0"),"B"=c("OK3","OK4","PB1","PB2"))
dict <- data.frame("pattern"=c("PB1","PB2"), "replacement"=c("OK1","OK2"))

apply(df[,c("A","B")],2, FUN=function(x) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(dict)) {
    x <- gsub(pattern = dict$pattern[i], replacement = dict$replacement[i],x)
  }
  return(x)
})
```

Or, if your `dict` data is too long you can generate a succession of all the `gsub` you need using a `paste` as a code generator :

```
paste0("df[,'A'] <- gsub(pattern = '", dict$pattern,"', replacement = '", dict$replacement,"',df[,'A'])")
```

It generates all the `gsub` lines for the "A" column :

```
"df[,'A'] <- gsub(pattern = 'PB1', replacement = 'OK1',df[,'A'])"
"df[,'A'] <- gsub(pattern = 'PB2', replacement = 'OK2',df[,'A'])"
```

Then you evaluate the code and wrap it in a lapply for the various columns :

```
lapply(c("A","B"), FUN = function(v) { eval(parse(text=paste0("df[,'", v,"'] <- gsub(pattern = '", dict$pattern,"', replacement = '", dict$replacement,"',df[,'",v,"'])"))) })
```

It's ugly but it works fine to avoid long loops.

**Edit** : for a exact matching between `df` and `dict` maybe you should use a boolean selection with `==` instead of `gsub()`.
(I don't use `match()` here because it selects only the first matching

```
df <- data.frame("A"=c("PB1","PB2","OK0","OK0","OK"),"B"=c("OK3","OK4","PB1","PB2","AB"))
dict <- data.frame("pattern"=c("PB1","PB2","OK"), "replacement"=c("OK1","OK2","ZE"))

apply(df[,c("A","B")],2, FUN=function(x) {
for (i in 1:nrow(dict)) {
     x[x==dict$pattern[i]] <- dict$replacement[i]
    }
   return(x)
 })
```

Comment: Thanks.Tried the first approach. But int the dict you can find stuffs as follows dict <- data.frame("pattern"=c("PB1","PB2","OK"), "replacement"=c("OK1","OK2","ZE")). So here it will change PB1 to OK1, then it will change OK1 to ZE1. And fixed=TRUE didn't help.

Comment: Maybe gsub is not adapted. See edit for a exact matching between df and dict.

Comment: Not all columns are atomic. I mean one column is like 'PB1,PB2,OK0" with commas. So gsub in this case is better. I will accept you answer. Because you gave me good insights. thanks.

Comment: Thanks ! Maybe you can mix the two options according to a test on the "atomicity" of the column ?